# Obtaining column name from array of strings and using it to alter SQL Table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL which accepts a String. The string contains a list of column names which contain the column name and the type

ex) "NAME VARCHAR, AGE NUMBER"

ALTER TABLE T1
ADD COLUMN NAME VARCHAR

I am working with Snowflake

My logic is correct, however I am struggling to properly write the syntax
In the code below, the alter table statement with the array is where I am stuck
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_COLUMNS_CONTEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTES("P_COL_NAME_SPACE_TYPE" VARCHAR(16777216))
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  COMMENT = 'Turns column string list into array'
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$

     var arr = [];
     var v_storing_passed_parameter = P_COL_NAME_SPACE_TYPE;
     arr = v_storing_passed_parameter.split(',');
     
     for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        try{
            var v_sqlCode = ***`ALTER TABLE CONTEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTES 
                             ADD COLUMN ' + arr[i];***
            var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
            var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
        }catch(err){
        errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
        errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;  
        throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
      }
        
     };
     
     return "success";
  $$;

    CALL ADD_COLUMNS_CONTEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTES('AGE NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_COLUMNS_CONTEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTES("P_COL_NAME_SPACE_TYPE" VARCHAR(16777216))
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  COMMENT = 'Turns column string list into array'
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$

     var arr = [];
     var v_storing_passed_parameter = P_COL_NAME_SPACE_TYPE;
     arr = v_storing_passed_parameter.split(',');
     
     for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        try{
            var v_sqlCode = `ALTER TABLE CONTEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTES ADD COLUMN ${arr[i]}`;
            var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
            var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
        }catch(err){
        errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
        errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;  
        throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
      }
        
     };
     
     return "success";
  $$;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me
May I ask, what is the difference between using
"ALTER TABLE CONTEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTES ADD COLUMN " + arr[i];
versus the solution you provided 
`ALTER TABLE CONTEXTUAL_ATTRIBUTES ADD COLUMN ${arr[i]}`;

Comment: You can terminate strings three ways in JavaScript, using single quotes, double quotes, or backticks. Backticks by far allow the most versatility. It allows multi-line strings and use of double and single quotes inside the string. This makes it a great option for SQL, which is often multi-line for readability and includes single and double quotes. The other thing it allows is use of replacement tokens in the form `${myValue}`. Any variable or expression inside the curly braces gets replaced with its string representation.